# Continuously monitor an ssh connection using tail -f?

Tags: jmeter

## My Situation

I am using the SSH Command tool to retrieve log info from a remote Linux server using the tail command. A separate thread group logs in users which causes the log file to update with the login information. To get the data I need, I use a regex extractor on the response data. For every thread jmeter creates a new ssh connection to retrieve the new messages in that log file.

Here's my current setup:

Thread Group
- Get random user
- Login User
- SSH into server using tail command
- Extract relevant data

## My Question

Instead of sshing into the Linux server every thread, causing extra load and log messages, I want to connect once at the start of the test and continuously extract from the log file using the tail -f command, for example, combined with the regex. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is not possible or at least not easy.

In order to be able to extract the data from the response using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) you need to have [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), it means that the SSH Command request **must be completed**. If you're going to use `tail -f` the request will never end.

If you want to minimize the number of connections you can consider using [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to establish the connection once and execute the commands within the bounds of a single [Session](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html).

If the above solution makes sense - consider migrating to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), you can find example code to execute remote command over SSH in i.e. [Exec.java class](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html)